# OpenCL, Synchronization execution of workitems in workgroup (not barriers and memory fetch)

Tags: synchronization, opencl, gpu, memory-barriers

@ Hi Everybody,

I'm implementing digital filter on AMD GPU by OpenCL.
The filter's feature is dependencies between neighboring elements.
Each element depends on elements on the left, on the top and on the top-right.
Please see [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxWCk_JLMhGUbjhxcGl1UG8ya3c/edit?usp=sharing) w/ image to get it better.

Such,

```
element 2 -> from 1.
element 3 -> from 2.
element 7 -> from 1, 2 (top, top-right).
element 8 -> from 7, 2, 3.
element 16 -> from 15, 10, 11 
etc... applying for each element from 2nd to 24th
```

All in all a few row might be executed parallel if row above is go ahead by 2 elements.

So, I've come to the question, **how to organize synchronization between elements???**
I didn't find any ways to organize synch inside workgroup. 
Barriers seems not to be appropriate mechanism since they are to organize simultaneous archiving check points while in my case it has to be synchronization w/ delay between threads.

There is one way which seems to be suitable. Using clEnqueueTask() and events (or clEnqueueNDRangeKernel w/ workgroup is equal <1, 1, 1>). 
But in this case I **can't use local memory** and it will be significantly slower.

**Question again: How to organize synchronization between threads in the same workgroup to effectively use fast local memory???**

Thanks in advance.
Please note,
- that 6x4 dimension only for illustration, indeed it's about 4K elements.
- "element" is 8x8 block of integer values.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your total count of work-items fits into a single work-group, you could probably solve this dependencies by using barriers. In detail you have to synchronize all work-items within the work-group for each dependency. This could be done by identifying each element running as a thread by its global index.

```
element 2 -> from 1.
BARRIER -------------------------------------------(SYNC WG)
element 3 -> from 2.
BARRIER -------------------------------------------(SYNC WG)
element 7 -> from 1, 2 (top, top-right).
BARRIER -------------------------------------------(SYNC WG)
element 8 -> from 7, 2, 3.
BARRIER -------------------------------------------(SYNC WG)
element 16 -> from 15, 10, 11.
```

When it comes to larger sets of data which will not fit into your workgroup-dimension, you probably have to use additional kernels and buffers. You also have to worry about elements whose dependencies are exceeding the border of a specific workgroup. Global synchronization could only be reached by using additional kernels in this case. See the example, elements are spread about different workgroups.

```
.____WG1_____.____WG2_____.____WG3_____.____WG4_____.
|           2|3           |            |            |
|           7|            |            |            |
|            |            |            |            |
|____________|____________|____________|____________|
|            |            |            |            |
|            |            |            |            |
|            |            |            |            |
|____WG5_____|____WG6_____|____WG7_____|____WG8_____|
```

But the main problem is: your algorithm and its dependencies **will cause a very bad SIMD-performance**. Not all of the threads are running simultaneous and so you will never charge the full capicity of your device.

I hope i understood your problem. For a better solution additional informations of your algorithm would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But again **BARRIERs**, how you offer them, are the way to **FULLY** serialize execution while I'm asking about synchronizing parallel threads. And Yes, 6x4 array is only for illustration actually it's 2K x 2K array...

Comment: At the moment i'm not sure if i understood your question completley. Barriers are imho mentioned to synchronize parallel threads within a workgroup and you can use it for synchronizing parallel threads. I thought it is your goal to implement a kind of serialized execution, to guarantee that all dependencies of a current element are fulfilled when it comes to its calculation.

Comment: no, the question is exact how to organise execution in parallel allowing some dependencies. Serialization is not a problem. Please, see comment below, I tried to explain it again. Hope it's a bit clear.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: "Does each work item need to sync with the others?"

Since typically digital filters only need to interact with the input data to provide an output. But they do not recursively use the output of the previous or neighbours items.

If that is the case, you don't need any sync mechanism at all.

There should be a BIG disclaimer in all the OpenCL guides saying: "Local memory is fast but private memory is even faster, if you don't need to use local memory, because you don't need to sync between threads, then simply don't use it."

In the specific case of filtering, it might be the case that neighbour cells need the same memory zones as input values. If that is the case, it is better to locally save it and avoid some global fetches. Since your algorithm only needs 3 values, your reuse factor is only 2/3. But considering the additional overhead of the local saving process, I would not expect heavy benefits from it.

If you still want to go down that road. Then you have to do two parts in your kernel: Fetch and filter. Each part separated by a barrier.

In the first part you need to copy local memory the area needed by the workgroup. This overlaps someparts with other workgroups (the overhead I said before).

Then after the memory is read, in the second step you simply process the filter and return the result. There is no need to sync this last part, since each item will affect only one output value.

Comment: For 1st question - Yes, it does. Each item (except of course, boundary) use filtered output values of their neighbors. Sync is needed.<br/> And LOCAL MEMORY I want to use exact to avoid second reading input data from GLOBAL memory. <br/>Please, note "element" is 8x8 block of integers, but not just int or float.

Comment: In that case your problem cannot be solved using OpenCL. At least not in an efficient way. Since your problem is serial (mainly).

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL can only synchronize within a workgroup, not across workgroups. If you need the latter, queue up sequential kernels.

From your problem description (which admittedly, I'm not *fully* understanding) it sounds like any given work item has dependencies on some subset of all prior work items, including some well outside the current work group. If that is true, you have a sequential problem, not a parallel problem. If that is the case, you need to figure out how to turn it into a parallel problem by removing or at least reducing these dependencies. Can you, for example, limit the amount of "look back" to be not greater than some number? If so, you can compute in parallel, items that far apart without dependencies. Or, maybe you can work on in parallel different problem sets (do just one work item from each, but many in parallel).

Comment: "dependencies..., including some well outside the current work group" - yes, there is, but sych of workgroups is other task. Let's leave it for time and suppose that workgroups are independent. Again, each element in the ROW is compute one by one, elements of row are calculated only sequentially. But rows might be calculated in parallel taking in to account than at least 2 elements of above row has been finished. For example elements 0-3 of row1 might be calculated when 0-4 from row0 has been finished. Or elem 0 of row3 - when elem 0-1 of row2 has been finished and so on.